# Reload an angular modal with new data everytime the modal opens

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on an angular web project which the main component class that loads a Modal to update a report. This Modal report has tabs, one of the tabs is the transaction tab which I am responsible for. The problem that I have is that when I close the update report modal and open it again the transactions tab still displays a list it loaded on the component initialized. I want the transactions tab to reload the data every time the update modal is opened. this where I load the data:

```
enter ngOnInit() {
    this.getTransactions();
    this.getAllTransmodes();
}code here
```

this is the method that gets the data:

```
getTransactions(): void {
    this.onDeselect();
    this.response = this.reportTransactionsTabService.getTransactions(this.selectedReport.xmlGuid)
        .subscribe(
            items => {
                this.transactions = items;
                this.filteredTransactions = this.transactions;
                this.totalTransactions = this.filteredTransactions.length
                this.filterValue = "";
                this.currentSortField = null;
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: Show your modal opening logic. Also, you could just call the logic that's in `ngOnInit` every time your `(click)` handler is fired to open the modal (assuming that's how it's opened).

Comment: We're going to need your whole code. But without it, I can only advise you to do `this.transactions = undefined` when your modal is closed (which I imagine is bound to `ngOnDestroy`)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to the problem. All I needed to do is inherit from the OnChanges (One of Angular's Life-cycle Hooks):

```
export class ReportTransactionsTabComponent implements OnInit, **OnChanges**
```

Then call the the functions that the load data in the ngOnChanges method:

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this.getTransactions();
    this.getAllTransmodes();
}
```

It will basically keep on calling those methods if there are changes to the report Transactions Tab

Answer (score 0):

The ngOnInit() is component lifeCycle hook which is specific to your PageComponent and gets called when your page is loading. As you are using a Tab to display the transaction data , so when you click the tab it will not be reloading your page again. So ngOnInit() method is not getting called in this case.

You should call a refresh/loadData method on click of your tab something like this :
`<div (click)="loadData()">TransactionTab</div>`

Also define the method in your component like

`loadData() {
    //Call the method for loading your data
    this.getTransactions(); 
   this.getAllTransmodes();
}`

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the life cycle hooks, I just need to implement the OnChanges from the  Transactions Compoent Class:                                                            export class ReportTransactionsTabComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{}, then calll the ngOnchanges method